# What does “# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4” mean in "gcc -E" output?

Tags: c, gcc

See following example:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -E foo.c | head
# 1 "foo.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command line>"
# 1 "foo.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 36 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/feature_tests.h" 1 3 4
# 30 "/usr/include/sys/feature_tests.h" 3 4
#pragma ident "%Z%%M%   %I%     %E% SMI"

$
```

I tried Google but I don't know what keywords I should use for searching. Any links to the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are linemarkers for identifying which source file and line a particular line of code came from.  They can be used to generate more accurate diagnostic messages, for example.  Documentation links:

1. [Preprocessor Output](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Preprocessor-Output.html)
2. [Line Control](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html)

You can use the `-P` option to omit them if you'd like.